# help understanding the "financing" of the current account

Tags: macroeconomics, balance-of-payments

I often hear phrases like country XYZ "finances its current account deficit through flows in its financial account". i have a tough time understanding this idea of "financing" a current account deficit and why it happens with certainty.

i understand there is an identity that says: current account + financial account + capital account = 0. so, if the first term is negative than the sum of the second two must offset, and i suppose that is what is meant by financing - but it is not intuitively clear to me why this must be the case

Comment: Shouldn't be the sentence read like this  : 
"When a country runs a current account deficit, it is building up liabilities to the rest of the world that are financed by flows in the financial account."

Comment: yes, sure - but what precisely does this mean?